# Automatically advance minor version number every build (VS 2008)

Tags: visual-studio-2008, assemblies

I use the assembly information version number - and advance it manually through the VS 2008.

Is there a way to advance the minor version number automatically each time I Build the solution ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used this [MSBuild Task](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/AutoIncrementBuildTask.aspx) to auto-increment my build numbers - requires a few manual modifications in your *.csproj or *.vbproj files, but it works quite flawlessly, and is quite flexible, too.

Comment: I think this targets what I need better, it will take me some time to test it, but it looks right ! thanks !

Comment: This is a little problem, I am using a svn controlled environment which locks the files if I don't check them out.
using this solution makes me lock the assembly.cs in order to build.
I guess there is no way to avoid this... but it takes the fun out of the solution...

Answer (score 1):

Visual studio have a build-in mecanism for that:

inside `AssemblyInfo.cs`, change the settings by this one:

```
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.*")]
```

Asterisk sign instructs Visual Studio to assign on each build a version 1.0.d.s, where d is the number of days since February 1, 2000, and s is the number of seconds since midnight/2.

EDIT:

Take a look at this webpage: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/ManagingAssemblyVersions.aspx there is many information about: how to manage the version number.

Comment: 10x, how can I tell which is the current number / have a "sid" - meaning -  if the project is in number 55 and I want it to start automatically from 56 ?
(or start from zero after a magor version number change ?)

Comment: If i remember correctly, the first generated number will be generated in function of the date, and the second one with a build number.
So you will get number like 1.0.4245.51002

Comment: Well, it works (vote up), but can't I control the start number ? 
I got: 1.0.0.31411 
and after 1 build it went to 31485 !
so it doesn't even jump sequentially....

Answer (score 0):

IIRC In your solution explorer, click on "Show all files", I believe it's the third one near the top of that window.

(double)click on "My Project."

Next, double-click on "AssemblyInfo.vb"

In the code editor, scroll down until you've reached the bottom.

Comment out

Replace

```
<Assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.0.0")>
```

with

```
<Assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.*.0")>
```

Click 'Save'.

Then you're done!

Comment: yeah,but that doesn't nicely advance the build number - it just grabs the current time and date adn sticks it in there, so your build numbers look something like 1.0.21643.23849 and so forth....

Comment: Thanks for that, ill make a note. I remember one of my co-workers mentioning it one time.

Answer (score 0):

One flexible option is to create a T4 template with version numbering scheme and reference a .cs file that Visual Studio generates from it. An example of such template:

<#@ template language="C#" #>
//
// This code was generated by a tool. Any changes made manually will be lost
// the next time this code is regenerated.
//

using System.Reflection;

[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.1.<#= this.RevisionNumber #>")]
[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("1.0.1.<#= this.RevisionNumber #>")]
<#+
    int RevisionNumber = (int)(DateTime.UtcNow - new DateTime(2010,1,1)).TotalDays;

## >

In this example revision number is set to the number of days since January 1st, 2010. But you can provide any custom numbering scheme, because it's plain C#.

I wrote a [blog post](http://bloggingabout.net/blogs/vagif/archive/2010/04/24/using-t4-templates-to-manage-assembly-version-information.aspx) which explains this technique in more details:

Comment: Thanks, I'll check your blog to understand this technique.